# Composite key one to second and one to third Entity Framework 6 code-first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a scenario to create key combination. Is there any way to do it with EF 6 code-first?

I have to add restriction with device and employee to don't be duplicated in the same branch. `branchId` is a foreign key.

I try to use below class but its allowing me to add branch = 1,device =2 and employee = 1.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Branch")]
    [Index("BranchEmpDev", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public long BranchId { get; set; }

    [Index("BranchEmpDev", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public string DevRegNumber { get; set; }

    [Index("BranchEmpDev", IsUnique = true, Order = 3)]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department>  Departments { get; set; }


}
```

below image is showing what I need.

[image]

Comment: Create key combination? Do you mean you are trying to create a compound key?

Comment: Yes i have to add restriction with device and employee to don't be dublicate in same branch

Comment: Setting bounty brings attention, but does not make the question better. To get meaningful answers, start by posting the entity class and related fluent configuration if any (the bare minimum for EF related question).

Comment: @IvanStoev I added the entity class and what i try. see edited question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, currently you have a single unique index (constraint) called "BranchEmpDev" on `(BranchId, DevRegNumber, EmployeeNumber)` field combination, but you want instead two unique indexes - one on `(BranchId, DevRegNumber)` field combination (let call it "BranchDev") and another on `(BranchId, EmployeeNumber)` field combination (let call it "BranchEmp").

It's possible, although not so intuitive (composite keys/indexes are not intuitive in EF6 in general). To do that with data annotations, you would use `IndexAttribute`s as in your current model, but with *different name* and apply them on the corresponding properties with the desired order. Which means that `BranchId` will have *two* `IndexAttributes` - one for each index it is part of.

The relevant part of the solution looks like this:

```
[ForeignKey("Branch")]
[Index("BranchEmp", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
[Index("BranchDev", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
public long BranchId { get; set; }

[Index("BranchEmp", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
[StringLength(10)]
public string DevRegNumber { get; set; }

[Index("BranchDev", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
[StringLength(10)]
public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
```

which generates the following part in the table creation migration (just for verification):

```
.Index(t => new { t.BranchId, t.EmployeeNumber }, unique: true, name: "BranchDev")
.Index(t => new { t.BranchId, t.DevRegNumber }, unique: true, name: "BranchEmp");
```

As you can see, EF consolidates the `IndexAttribute`s with the *same name* and uses the `Order` to build the composite column list.